# Jest toEqual not passing due to format of JSON

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have this test:

```
it('Outputs correct ES6 code', () => {

  const updateCodeGenerationOptions = actions.updateSourceCode(sampleJson)
  expect(jsonCodeTools(undefined, updateCodeGenerationOptions))
    .toEqual(
      {
        'options': {'outputCodeType': 'ES6'},
        'outputCodeFromJSON': '<pre>export class Foo {<br>  constructor (object) {<br>    this.shouldBeNumber1 = object.shouldBeNumber1; <br>    this.shouldBeString1 = object.shouldBeString1; <br>    this.shouldBeBoolean1 = object.shouldBeBoolean1; <br>    this.shouldBeFragment1 = new shouldBeFragment1(object.shouldBeFragment1); <br>  } <br>}<br>export class  shouldBeFragment1{<br>  constructor (object) {<br>    this.FshouldBeNumber1 = object.FshouldBeNumber1; <br>    this.FshouldBeString1 = object.FshouldBeString1; <br>    this.FshouldBeBoolean1 = object.FshouldBeBoolean1; <br>  } <br>}<br></pre>',
        'sourceCode': JSON.stringify({
          'shouldBeNumber1': '1',
          'shouldBe String1': '.1',
          'shouldBeBoolean1': 'false',
          'shouldBeFragment1': {
            'FshouldBeNumber1': '1',
            'FshouldBeString1': 'bar',
            'FshouldBeBoolean1': 'false'
          }
        })
      }
    )
})
```

When it runs it fails with this:

[image]

So to me this is just a formating issue, how would I get this test to pass?

Answer (score 0):

You do have a formatting issue but your test is genuinely not passing anyway. Look at `shouldBeFragment1`; expected value is false, but the actual value is an object.

For the formatting issue you should `JSON.parse` and then `JSON.stringify` the actual output so that it is not pretty-printed (or better yet remove the pretty printing from the unit under test).

Comment: shouldBeFragment1 is not expected to be false

Comment: Well, the Jest output says that it is expected to be false. So.

Comment: It's in the image you posted in your  original question.

Comment: can you paste the exact screenshot part please?